# Python: Replacing certain Unicode entities with entities from dictionary

Tags: python, regex, unicode, backslash

I have read already much about the problem of backslash escaping in python strings (and backslash recognition in Python in different encodings) and using backslashes in regular expressions, but still cannot solve my problem. I would highly appreciate any help (links, code examples, etc).

I am trying to replace hexadecimal codes in strings with certain elements from dictionary using **re**. The codes are of type *'\uhhhh'* where *hhhh* is hex number.

I select strings from sqlite3 table; by default they are read as unicode and not as "raw" unicode strings.

```
import re
pattern_xml = re.compile(r"""
(.*?)                       
([\\]u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})
(.*?)                           
""", re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
uni_code=['201C','201D']
decoded=['"','"']
def repl_xml(m):
    item=m.group(2)
    try: decodeditem=decoded[uni_code.index(item.lstrip('\u').upper())]
    except: decodeditem=item
    return m.group(1) + "".join(decodeditem) + m.group(3)

#input        
text = u'Try \u201cquotated text should be here\u201d try'
#text after replacement
decoded_text=pattern_xml.subn(repl_xml,text)[0]
#desired outcome
desired_text=u'Try "quotated text should be here" try'
```

So, I want _decoded_text_ to be equal to _desired_text_.

I did not succeed in replacing single backslash with double backslash or forcing python to treat text as raw unicode string (so that backslashes are treated literally and not like escape characters).  I also tried using re.escape(text) and setting re.UNICODE, but in my case that doesn't help.
I'm using Python 2.7.2.

Which solutions can be found to this problem?

Edit:
I have actually found out a possible solution to this problem on [StandardEncodings](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/standard-encodings.html) and [PythonUnicodeIntegration](http://www.egenix.com/www2002/python/unicode-proposal.txt) by applying the following encoding to *input*:

```
text.encode('unicode_escape')
```

Is there anything else to do?

Comment: [\\]u[0-9a-fA-F]{,4} != [\\]u[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}

Comment: sorry, comma should not be there: [\\]u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}

Comment: Can you simply post the smallest amount of code possible which reproduces the error among with an input string and the desired output?

Comment: @npobedina. Do you _really_ end up with strings in _all_ of the three formats that you have shown? If so, then that is a bug which needs to be fixed _before_ you tackle the issue of decoding the entity/char refs.

Comment: actually I have strings only of format _text3_ , which caused my problem (other strings I added as examples). but following @FailedDev advice I'll edit the post with shorter piece of code and clearer task :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample text doesn't contain any backslashes. The `\u201c` is just a way of representing a unicode character:

```
>>> text = u'Try \u201cquotated text should be here\u201d try'
>>> '\\' in text
False
>>> print text
Try “quotated text should be here” try
```

A regex is not really required here. Just translate the target unicode characters as desired:

```
>>> table = {0x201c: u'"', 0x201d: u'"'}
>>> text.translate(table)
u'Try "quotated text should be here" try'
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it does exactly what I need. I just got obsessed with regexp and could not think of anything else =)